# ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (can't write unknown attribute `flights_count`):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing some refactoring and I have seen this project for a while and it worked from what I last recall. But the issue is, I am trying to create a flight and I keep getting "***ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (can't write unknown attribute `flights_count`):***" when trying create a new flight.

As far my models in place:

My Flight, Pilot models

```
class Flight < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :passengers
    belongs_to :destination
    belongs_to :pilot, counter_cache: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :passengers
    belongs_to :user, class_name: "Flight" ,optional: true 
    validates_presence_of :flight_number
    validates :flight_number, uniqueness: true
    scope :order_by_flight_international, -> { order(flight_number: :asc).where("LENGTH(flight_number) > 3") }
    scope :order_by_flight_domestic, -> { order(flight_number: :asc).where("LENGTH(flight_number) <= 2 ") }
    

    def dest_name=(name)
        
        self.destination = Destination.find_or_create_by(name: name)
    end

    def dest_name
        
        self.destination ? self.destination.name : nil
    end

    def pilot_name=(name)
        self.pilot = Pilot.find_or_create_by(name: name)
    end

    def pilot_name
        
        self.pilot ? self.pilot.name : nil
    end

    

end


class Pilot < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, optional: true
    has_many :flights
    has_many :destinations, through: :flights
    
    validates_presence_of :name, :rank
    validates :name, uniqueness: true
    scope :top_pilot, -> { order(flight_count: :desc).limit(1)}
   
end
```

***Edit***
Flight Controller

```
class FlightsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :verified_user
    layout 'flightlayout'

    def index
        @flights = Flight.order_by_flight_international
        @dom_flights = Flight.order_by_flight_domestic
    end

    
    
    def new
        @flight = Flight.new
        10.times {@flight.passengers.build}
       
    end

    def create
        @flight = Flight.new(flight_params)
        # byebug
        if @flight.save!
  
            redirect_to flight_path(current_user,@flight)
        else
            flash.now[:danger] = 'Flight Number, Destination, and Pilot have to be selected at least'
            render :new
  
           
        end
    end
  private

    def flight_params
        params.require(:flight).permit(:flight_number,:date_of_flight, :flight_time, :flight_id, :destination_id, :pilot_id, :pilot_id =>[], :destination_id =>[], passengers_attributes:[:id, :name])
    end
    
    
end
```

***Edit***
Flights, Pilot Schemas

```
create_table "flights", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "pilot_id"
    t.integer "destination_id"
    t.string "flight_number"
    t.string "date_of_flight"
    t.string "flight_time"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "pilots", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "rank"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "flight_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "flight_count", default: 0
  end
```

As I said before when I last worked on this project everything was working fine, but I am faced with this issue. What am I doing wrong this time.

Comment: Show us your controller and schema of this table

Comment: @ZainArshad I just updated it for you

Comment: Detination_id and pilot_id is a being used two times in your flight_params, is it deliberate?

Comment: No that is on accident

Comment: i see no flights_count attributes on your model flights schema, there is no flight_count method also in your model. do you have that somewhere?

Comment: @dedypuji I have that in another method called Pilots, I'll update this to show that as well.

Comment: can you provide schema for your pilot model please

Comment: @dedypuji You should see it now

Comment: it's typo. there is no flights_count. flight_count is exist in your pilot

Comment: @dedypuji the error I posted mentions flights_count. I said the same at first, but I kept seeing flight_count in my schema, and the pilot model. The weird thing is this was working months back.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have defined a `counter_cache` in your `Flight` model for `pilots`. When you just use `counter_cache: true` to define it, `ActiveRecord` will look for a column named `flights_count` in your `pilots` table but I see that you have named it as `flight_count` instead. You can either rename the column to `flights_count` or pass the custom column name to it by using `counter_cache: :flight_count`

Source https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache

Comment: That actually worked! I replaced the boolean with flight count and it worked as you said. It was better than making adjustments to my columns. Thank you sir!